# What’s the water pressure at the surface of earth in kPa?

Tags: pressure

I need to know this to solve a problem, but cannot find information on it.
What is the pressure of the atmosphere at sea level in kPa?

Comment: The question is not quite clear. If you mean hydrostatic pressure then what is important is the height of the water column above the point of interest. If you are considering an infinitely small height then the pressure will also be infinitely small.

Comment: "The question is not quite clear" exactly what I thought when I read the problem.

Comment: Well, if you think the question is unclear, why do you ask it here? Do you think it becomes clearer if you repeat it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be the same, for a still pond of water, as the pressure of the air immediately above it, *i.e.* approximately $100{\rm kPa}$.

To think carefully about this, you would think of a layered fluid (in this case a column of air above a column of water) and calculate the compressive stress at each position along the column. Imagine a balloon of air in space where the pressure is nought. The balloon's elastic skin stretches until its tension exactly opposes the pressure of the gas within. Then imagine dragging the balloon towards Earth. It will shrink, because the pressure of the atmosphere on the skin from the outside partially balances the pressure from the gas on the inside, and the elastic skin doesn't need to be so stretched to balance the nett force from the inside.

As the balloon enters the water and dives, the effect is the same, aside from that suddenly the shrinking rate per unit depth becomes much higher, reflecting water's higher density.